# "The license located at config/license.key belongs to gridserver.com"

Tags: license

Getting this notification at the top of the control panel. This is a solo/free license version of Craft.

It happened after I updated my client's domain's DNS to point to my server.

When I originally set it up, I installed craft on my media temple grid server. The access domain for it at that time was: http://centraldsmhomes.com.s179491.gridserver.com. As soon as I updated the DNS for centraldshhomes.com to point to my mediatemple server, I got the license issue.

Can't seem to find any solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to log into id.craftcms.com and re-assign the license to the appropriate domain e.g. centraldshhomes.com.

Craft automatically gets the top level domain when you grab a license, as part of our workflow we just assign it closer to go live / deployment.